# How to combine two sentences by using "who"?

Tags: american-english, relative-clauses

I want to combine two sentences into one sentence by using "who", but I'm not sure how to do it.

For example:

> 1. We are not super user.
> 2. We don't have root authority.

Can I combine them into:

> 3. We who don't have root authority are not super user.

Is this #3 sentence correct?

Comment: You have done well without our help! (But: *we* are not *super users*, plural - or *we* don't have superuser status.)

Comment: Got it. But I think that I still need you guys experties help.

Comment: Another option is: *We are not super users, who have root authority.*

Comment: If the two statements are both true statements, then a simple statement using "and"
We are not super user and we don't have root authority.
If the there is a requirement tying the two together, then
If we don't have root authority, then we can't be super users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one super user, the root account. So "we" can never be super users. "Super user" has a special meaning. Also, if you do not have the password to login as the root user or sudo permissions on su to become the root user, then anyone you are talking to should know that you are not a privileged user. So to communicate what you are actually trying to, you should be able to just say the following to someone:

"We do not have any access to login or become the root user."

Comment: I want to know which part do you felt you have to leave the comment here like above that? That's interesting you know the super user.

Comment: If I understand your questions correctly, I was trying to help phrase another option you might have in communicating the intent given the specific topic of the root user you are asking about. I am hoping it was helpful, if not I apologize.

Comment: Sorry @Kirk, Would you please let me know once again what how much understand you my comment just before I leaved.

Comment: @Carter, if you are asking how much I know about the root user and access to it, the answer is I know a lot. How can I be of assistance?

Answer (score 2):

> We who don't have root authority are not super user.

requires commas!

> We, who don't have root authority, are not super userS (As StoneyB suggests).

However, there are dozens of way to tell this including those ones in the comments.

> We are not super users, who have root authority *(-Jim)*

[Good to note Wichita Steve's comment as well. Are those both statements true? Or one depends on another? Or one restricts the fact of another? - this all is a matter of clarification].

Taking it further, another thing could be simply stating why aren't you super users.

> We are not super users *as* we don't have root authority.

Comment: We are not super users, who have root authority looks more natural

Answer (score 1):

1. We are not super users.
2. We don't have root authority.

These are two simple statements. To combine them in a simple way, we can say "We are not super users, who have root authority. There is nothing wrong grammatically with the PO's sentence "We who don't have root authority are not super users", but I think when we say "We who" it  makes the sentence a bit emphatic.

Comment: making it a non-restrictive clause will clarify 'we who' matter. I said that in my answer.

Comment: Maulik, it's OK. But can we make it a restrictive clause as the PO has done? "We who don't have root authority are not super users". If no, he is wrong. If yes, he is right.